# QTableWidget::setCellWidget() disables signals from QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qwidget, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget instance with its cellEntered(int,int) signal associated to a slot X (that higlights the row in which the cell is contained). Also I have one column containing check boxes.

The problem is adding the checkboxes to the cells of the table using QTableWidget::setCellWidget() method:

```
QTableWidgetItem *checkBoxItem = new QTableWidgetItem("");
ui->tableWidget->setItem(rowCount, column, checkBoxItem);
QCheckBox* checkBox = new QCheckBox();
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(rowCount, column, checkBox);
connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
    this, SLOT(checkbox_clicked(bool)));
```

makes the slot X not to be called when the cursor is over a cell in that column.

The problem is not particular for check boxes but for other types of widgets too.

I have read something about the SignalMapper class in some posts, but that class seems to be useful to map signal from the widget to a slot. Instead, my problem is relative to a signal from the table.

Any suggestion?

Cheers,

Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use QTableWidgetItem and set it to checkable with [QTableWidgetItem::setCheckState(Qt::CheckState state)](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#setCheckState)?

```
QTableWidgetItem *check_item = new QTableWidgetItem;
check_item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
```

You can also do it with flags.

```
check_item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
```

Connect [QTableWidget::itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem * item)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged) signal to a slot, and check if the item is checked there.

Comment: Yes, I considered that alternative because it allows me to process all the signals from QTableWidget, which is a must to higlight rows. Anyway, I made the question because: 1) I can't understand the general fact that inserting ANY widget in a cell makes it difficult to process signals from QTableWidget. 2) Using the check state of the cell seems not be flexible enough to operate over the position and style of the check box as if I use a QCheckBox. Thanks for your answer, thuga!